# I have a problem in my React.js or Stardog server

Tags: reactjs, stardog

I cloned the GitHub repository for the React.js tutorial, then I installed the dependencies.

But I can't get the data from the database when I open the https:localhost:3000, and I have an error when I try to add data to the database. The error is showing at the console in the browser:

> XHRPOSThttp://localhost:5820/StarWarsDB/update
> [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 35ms]
>
> XHRPOSThttp://localhost:5820/StarWarsDB/query
> [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 34ms]

When I start Stardog server, an error is showing in the terminal:

> ERROR 2023-06-15T13:15:00,286+0300 [main] com.complexible.stardog.protocols.http.server.StardogHttpServiceLoader:createService(132): Unable to create an instance of HttpService class com.complexible.stardog.protocols.http.cache.server.CacheHttpService, missing compatible constructor

Everything is in the screenshots which I uploaded. How I can fix it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am expecting the error is not in the React.js app, I think it is in the Stardog server, maybe something I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the Stardog people said the error can be safely ignored for now, as it will be fixed in a subsequent release.

[Community](https://community.stardog.com/t/server-start-error/4433/12)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).